# Does flooring need to be done before built-in wardrobes?

Tags: flooring

I am just preparing to purchase a house that needs renovations done. If we can afford both we would like to redo the flooring to timber and also have built-in wardrobes installed. If we cannot do both we are considering just doing the wardrobes first and then flooring one or two years later. Is it possible to do it in that order? Or would we need to have the flooring done first and then the wardrobes installed on top of them?

Comment: By "wardrobe", do you mean a built in closet with full, floor-to-ceiling walls made out of studs and covered in drywall or plaster or similar, or do you mean a movable piece of furniture in which clothes are placed/hung?

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, I am thinking closets with full floor to ceiling walls. Something fixed and non-moveable.

Comment: I appreciate the check-mark, but you may want to wait a bit longer to see if anyone else chimes in. My general rule: let it sit for 48 hours to ensure I've got a good answer and all the possibilities...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend that any new walls, including those for built-in closets/wardrobes be done *before* the final finish flooring goes down.

You would want to build on the subfloor, nailing the sole plate of the wall down to the subfloor (preferably into joists below, if at all possible), and not having to worry about trying to cut through finish flooring in 10 or 20 years when you (or someone else) want to redo the floors again.