# Would I need to refinish floors after removing walls and patching the flooring?

Tags: walls, flooring

I am planning on making a bid for a property but it needs renovations done. Two of those are the floors and taking down some walls to open up the house more.

Ideally we would be able to do both at the same time but due to costs we may only be able to do the flooring first and then take down the walls a year or two later. If we were to install timber floors first and then take the walls down later, would that require a redo of the floors? I am assuming yes and the advice is probably to wait to do them together but would like to hear from the experts as I am quite clueless on this.

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of [your other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/208885/does-flooring-need-to-be-done-before-built-in-wardrobes) and my answer applies to both.

Comment: Hey @FreeMan, so regardless of whether erecting a new wall or taking one down they should be done first before laying down of a new floor?

What would be the implications of doing the floor first then taking down the wall? Could you not fill the gap where the wall was the same timber flooring?

Comment: You sure could. At the cost of _significantly_ more time in ripping down boards to fit in the gaps and face nailing because you've had to cut off the groove (if T&G flooring) and trying to match the finish of the patch to what was there and has now aged a year or 2 (or 3 or 4...). There's also the possibility of damaging the new(er) flooring in the demolition/construction process. If you look at _any_ new home construction, finish flooring is usually the 2nd to last thing to happen. Only cabinet installation happens later (but not always).